# Probability the other child is also a boy: a linear algebra approach?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, computational-mathematics

The classic conditional probability problem states: *you learn that somebody has two children and that one of them is a boy; what is the probability both children are boys*?
As a prior we have two **independent discrete uniform** random variables: $X_{1}$ -- sex of the first child and $X_{2}$ -- sex of the second child:
$$p(X_{1}) = \begin{cases}0.5 \; | \; x_{1} = B \\ 0.5 \; | \; x_{1}=G\end{cases}$$
$$p(X_{2}) = \begin{cases}0.5 \; | \; x_{2} = B \\ 0.5 \; | \; x_{2}=G\end{cases}$$
We use the **multiplication rule** to get the **joint uniform discrete pdf** (I know, I should call it pmf), which is:
$$p(X_{1},X_{2}) = \begin{cases}
                                0.25 \; | \; x_{1} = B, x_{2}=G \\ 
                                0.25 \; | \; x_{1} = G, x_{2}=B \\
                                0.25 \; | \; x_{1} = B, x_{2}=B \\
                                0.25 \; | \; x_{1} = G, x_{2}=G \\
                   \end{cases}$$
Now we are given additional information (evidence) that one the children is a boy, so we can condition the distribution, i.e. **slice and scale** it to arrive at.
$$p(X_{1},X_{2} | X_{1} \cup X_{2} = B ) = \begin{cases}
                                0.33 \; | \; x_{1} = B, x_{2}=G \\ 
                                0.33 \; | \; x_{1} = G, x_{2}=B \\
                                0.33 \; | \; x_{1} = B, x_{2}=B \\
                   \end{cases}$$
Now this case writeout is all very ugly and manual (but at least manageable due to low 2-dimensionality). **Is there a nice elegant way with linear algebra to get this conditional distribution**? There becomes even more of a need for this when we start adding additional independed random variables like $X_{3}$ -- the first child is born on a particular day of the week, $X_{4}$ -- the second child is born on a particular day of the week; and condition say on Tuesdays.